# What are the new datasheet features in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: list, data-view-web-part, list-view, datasheet

What are the new features with Datasheet functionality in SharePoint 2010 as compared to 2007?

Areas of focus:

- Ability to control column width, Show/Hide, freeze header row?
- File operations from Datasheet view (e.g., 2007 only allowed Read-Only file access)
- Concurrent editors?

Comment: We did some test around using DevExpress ASPXGridView that comes with SharePoint webpart that renders any list in a grid that supports the ability to control column width, Show/Hide, freeze header row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there are not significant improvements for Datasheet functionality for end users in SharePoint 2010, and I haven't seen any in your focus areas.